# The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Estoy utilizando Xamarin.Forms con base de datos local sqlite-net-pcl, creé un proyecto multiplataforma para Android, IOs y otros dos DLL para crear las clases del motor y acceso. He estado ejecutando el proyecto sin problemas pero hoy me salió el siguiente error:

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.ObjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
> for Android profile?
> File name: 'System.ObjectModel.dll'
>    at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>  reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>    at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
> reference)
>    at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
>    at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
>    at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.<GetTypeAndBaseTypes>d__1.MoveNext()
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>    at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.IsSubclassOf(TypeDefinition
> type, String typeName)
>    at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaTypeScanner.AddJavaTypes(List`1
> javaTypes, TypeDefinition type)
>    at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaTypeScanner.GetJavaTypes(IEnumerable`1
> assemblies, IAssemblyResolver resolver)
>    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
> res)
>    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Execute()
>    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()texto
> destacado
>    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()   SQLiteProyecto.Android
> ```

y por más que estoy mirando por internet no doy con ello.
¿Le ha surgido este mismo error a alguien? ¿Lo pudisteis solucionar?
Un saludo,
Miguel

Comment: Ve a Nuget, busca "objectmodel" y instala/actualiza el paquete, a ver si soluciona el problema

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, ya lo hice al igual que con el Xamarin.Forms.....pero nada de momento.

Comment: Lo hiciste para todos los proyectos de la solucion?

Comment: Si, incluso he desinstalado el paquete de objectModel y lo he vuelto a instalar y nada

Comment: Pues si ya has probado eso y a limpiar la solución, no se que mas decirte lo siento :)

Comment: Muchas gracias de todas formas @Pikoh. Cuando hablas de limpiar la solución a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Boton derecho en el proyecto, limpiar. O mejor, boton derecho en la solucion(limpiar solucion

Comment: Eso no lo había hecho y se ha quitado el error. Gracias por tu ayuda @Pikoh

Comment: Me alegro de que se haya resuelto. No lo propuse antes porque es lo primero que se suele hacer :)